# Put edges of a matrix to zero

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, pattern-matching, replacement

I have to set the first and last rows and columns to zero rows and columns.

I tried with the first column:

```
For[a = 1, a <= 3, a++, M = ReplacePart[mat, {a, 1} -> 0]; Print[M]]
```

> {{0,1,1},{1,1,1},{1,1,1}
>
> {{1,1,1},{0,1,1},{1,1,1}}
>
> {{1,1,1},{1,1,1},{0,1,1}}

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please, read the full documentation on `ReplacePart`. Also, it's good practice to include self contained examples -- in this case your initialisation of `mat` is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array  = ArrayReshape[Range[5 7], {5, 7}];
Fold[ArrayPad, array, {-1, 1}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 0 \\
>  0 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 0 \\
>  0 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also

```
ArrayPad[ArrayPad[array, -1], 1] 
ArrayPad[array[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]], 1] 
array (1 - MorphologicalPerimeter[array]) 
MapAt[0 &, array, {{All, {1, -1}}, {{1, -1}, All}}] 
ReplacePart[array, {1 | Dimensions[array][[1]], _} | {_, 1 | Dimensions[array][[2]]} :> 0]
```

all give the same result.

Comment: Henrik brought up an important issue on array (un)packing, please see my comment below his answer.

Comment: Thank you @LLlAMnYP.

Answer (score 5):

```
m = 2000;
n = 1000;
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n}];

First@RepeatedTiming[


  M = mat;
  M[[{1, -1}, All]] = 0.;
  M[[2 ;; -2, {1, -1}]] = 0.;


  ]
```

> 0.0039

Comment: Your method doesn't unpack array because you set the elements to real `0.`. If you modify kglr's solution to `Fold[ArrayPad[##, 0.] &, array, {-1, 1}]`, it also doesn't unpack.

Comment: Yeah, I've just observed that and deleted that remark. It's still about three times faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ArrayReshape[Range[5 17], {5, 17}];  // after kglr

Transpose[Transpose[array.DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}]].DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1,
  1, 1, 0}]] // MatrixForm
```

Or, more generally:

```
array // Transpose[Transpose[#.SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 0, 
ConstantArray[Dimensions[#][[2]], 2] -> 0, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, 
Dimensions[#][[2]]]].SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 0, 
ConstantArray[Dimensions[#][[1]], 2] -> 0, Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, 
Dimensions[#][[1]]]] & // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 0 \\
>  0 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 0 \\
>  0 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$